# Determine the window name/number in iTerm2

Tags: python, macos, applescript, iterm2

I am using iTerm2 on MacOS (Sierra). I have multiple instances of iterm2 running, each has a title that are prefixed with a number which increments with each running window.

I would like to run a shell command to return this number on the command line, does any one know how to get this information?

I am looking for something like:

```
$ iterm_get_number()
2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the names using applescript, the following script dumps a list of the open iTerm windows. Since I am interested in using these names in a python script I included a small snippet for doing this as well.

---

get_window_names.applescript

```
on run
    set returnNames to {}
    tell application "iTerm"
        repeat with theWindow in windows
            tell theWindow
                set end of returnNames to get name
            end tell
        end repeat
    end tell
    return returnNames
end run
```

---

python for extracting information from above script

```
out = subprocess.check_output(['osascript', 'get_window_names.applescript'])
print [x.strip() for x in out.split(',')]
```